# How to deal with method rename when using Osherove's convention for unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, refactoring

I like the unit tests naming convention recommended by Roy Osherove where unit tests look like this:

**SomeMethod_Scenario_ExpectedResults**

For `SomeMethod`, there will usually be more test methods that follow this convention and the question is how to deal with `SomeMethod` rename. I quite don't like the idea of going through all of the unit tests manually and renaming them one by one.

Is there a tool to help with this? Or maybe this is a weakness of Osherove's convention and I should go with something like this [nested classes approach](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/02/structuring-unit-tests.aspx)?

Comment: Can't you use a conventional search & replace, solution-wide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is somewhat of an edge case which probably isn't worth changing test naming strategies over.

Global search and replace is the obvious workaround.

Resharper's renaming functionality can optionally rename related string and comments too but I don't think it handles substrings inside method names.  If it is *really* important to you then you can always write your own VS plugin to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's called "Search and Replace" :) I find that renaming public methods after writing more than 2-3 tests is quite uncommon though.